# Using KendoUI Grid, How would you add a optional image or icon into the row template?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

I'm New to KendoUI. (Who isn't right?) I have a grid and I'm using a row templates. My dataset contains several boolean values. I want to insert an Icon after a product name as a visual indicator as to a product's status.

Example if the product falls below a threshold count I want to show a low inventory icon. If the product has more orders than inventory I want to show a different warning icon. So most products won't have any icons. But some could have multiple icons.

Does anyone have an great solution for this problem? How would I format the template so that I  can show or hide icons based on a boolean value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the RowTemplate to set a CSS class based on the value of the cell.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/rowtemplate.html

For instance, consider a grid with 2 columns, Name and Status. You could make a row template like:

```
var rowTemplate = "<tr><td class='#= Status #'></td><td>#= Name #</td></tr>";
```

And make CSS classes for each status:

```
.status1 { background-image: Url("/images/status1image.gif"); }
.status2 { background-image: Url("/images/status2image.gif"); }
```

Then apply the RowTemplate to the grid.  As the data changes the  CSS class should show the appropriate image.

I haven't tried this exactly - but it should work just fine.